# How to Migrate Kafka Cluster with No Downtime Using MM2?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I need to migrate our production Kafka cluster to a new cluster with more capacity, and have been researching how to do this with no downtime.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqRiagSnYfQ) has been helpful, but from my understanding of using MirrorMaker2 there will inevitably be downtime at some point, whether it be cutting your consumers over to the new Kafka cluster after you've replicated to it, or when you cut your producers over to the new cluster and no longer are using the original cluster at all.

Does anyone have experience with this that can lend some insight?

From what I can see the closest option to no downtime is setting up parallel clusters, including applications, consumers, and producers for each cluster. This is obviously very resource intensive, but does anyone know if there's a better way?

To give more detail, I'm planning to turn on MirrorMaker2 on my current cluster, which we can call Cluster A, to replicate data/consumer offsets to a new cluster (Cluster B) that I've set up and created all requisite topics on prior to turning on MM2. MM2 will be turned on only with the configuration to send A->B.

Thanks, and let me know if I can provide further details.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, for the basics of a migration. Don't shut down the source. You will have no downtime. Your alternative solution is to simply add hardware to the *existing cluster*. Then use `kafka-reassign-partitions` to increase replication for all partitions, all topics, etc. Then let the replication happen by tracking ISRs, then run the same command to remove the old replicas/brokers.

In the latter scenario, your clients don't need to change bootstrap servers to the new cluster until you finally decommission the old names. This is one reason to additionally have a TCP Reverse proxy for clients to interact with, rather than individually setting the brokers in any config.